# update existing version of mysql 5.6.35 to 5.7.17

Tags: mysql

I have mysql 5.6.35 installed on kali linux. How do I update it to 5.7.17 ?

I have tried mysql_upgrade which gives following error

```
Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
Error: Failed while fetching Server version! Could be due to unauthorized access.
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass root password:

```
mysql_upgrade -u root -p
```

However this won't be enough to upgrade to 5.7.x

First download and install the mysql community release repo from https://repo.mysql.com/:

```
cd ~
wget http://repo.mysql.com/mysql-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh mysql*.rpm
rpm -qa | grep mysql | grep release
mysql-community-release-el7-7.noarch
```

You might need to follow this guide on how to enable the subrepo, depending on what you previously downloaded from https://repo.mysql.com/:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html

Basically you need to disable old subrepo and enable the dev one:

```
yum-config-manager --disable mysql56-community
yum-config-manager --enable mysql57-community-dmr
```

You can check the status of the subrepos:

```
yum repolist all | grep mysql5..c
```

And eventually upgrade mysql:

```
yum clean all
yum upgrade
yum autoremove
mysql_upgrade -u root -p
```

Verify installed version:

```
rpm -qa | grep mysql | grep server
mysql-community-server-5.7.17-1.el7.x86_64
```

Extra:
You can always check a .rpm contents, for example:

```
 rpm2cpio ~/mysql-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm | cpio -idmv
 cd ~/etc/yum.repos.d
 cat mysql-community.repo
```

This way you can see what subrepos are added.